# Why does getcontext and setjmp save different registers in glibc-x86-64

Tags: linux, glibc, context-switch, setjmp, ucontext

Here are their source codes:
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/getcontext.S;hb=HEAD
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=sysdeps/x86_64/setjmp.S;hb=HEAD

As you can see, getcontext also saves floating point context and registers r8 and r9 which setjmp does not. What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like both routines are wrong. Setjmp should not ignore floating point state and getcontext should not save r8,r9.

Reference:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/context/doc/html/context/rationale/x86_and_floating_point_env.html

Comment: Then? Did you report this as bugs?

Comment: The one you're mentioning look serious problems, if confirmed. I honestly would expect more complains in this case, unless these are just reference implementations and the kernel is providing the actual code. Why don't you open a quick [ticket](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=glibc)? They seem quite responsive. I would but I have little knowledge: I'm just evaluating use of setjmp/getcontext.

Comment: getcontext should save r8,r9 because it's meant for saving the entire thread state, not just returning from a non-local jump (e.g. setjmp). ucontext_t is used in signal handlers for changing CPU state on SIGILL/SIGSEGV/etc.